# Navbar extending outside of container frame

Tags: html, css, nav

I'm hand-coding my first website, and it's been a fun adventure so far, but I've run into a css glitch with the navigation menu. [Here's my website-in-progress](http://www.daniellmusic.com/wp-content/test/index.html). On my 15" laptop, when I initially load the site, the nav bar extends to the full-width of the container (80% width of the screen) as I expect it to. However, if I zoom the webpage, or view it through different resolutions through screenfly, the nav bar extends past the container and also the header image becomes short. Can anyone help me figure out why this is? Below is the css, then the html

```
*{ margin: 0 auto;}


body {
background:black; 
margin: 0 auto; 
font-family:georgia, times,serif; 
}

#outer-content-wrapper{
    position:relative;
    height:100%;
    width:80%;
    margin:0 auto;
}
#navwrap{
    margin:0;
    height:60px;
    width:100%;
}

#nav{
    position:relative;
    background:black; 
    height:60px;
    width:100%;
    border-top-style:dashed;
    border-bottom-style:dashed;
    border-width:1px;
    border-color:#696969;
    z-index:9000;
    }`

<div id="outer-content-wrapper">
<div id="header">
    <div id="greenlight"></div>
</div>

<div id="navwrap">  
<div id="nav">
    <div id="logo"></div>
        <div class="menu">
            <div class="pagesmenu">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#bio">bio</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#music">listen</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#contact">contact</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://blog.danielLmusic.com">blog</a> </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

Peace

Answer (score 0):

use bootstrap instead of plain css. Bootstraps helps to work your site as per screen resoultion  http://getbootstrap.com/. use my html code for help

HTML:

```
<html >
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>MENU</title>
<link href="bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="custom.css" />
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/media.css" />    
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src= "respond.min.js"></script>
        <![endif]--> 

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="application.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">

    <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
      <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
  </div>

  <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
    </form>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
</nav>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Your complete site will pe resposive and can also work on mobile

Comment: Thank you. I actually just met someone the other day - a web developer - who mentioned the bootstrap concept to me. As you also said, it seems like the way to go. I'm still curious, though, what is wrong with my css.